# Latex pgfplots y-tick with exponential scaling

Tags: pgfplots

I'm tryng to make a plot with the pgfplots package. My code is the following

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[         
   xlabel={ Time (seconds)},
   ylabel={Exp},
   xmin=0, xmax=18,
   ymin=0, ymax=2000000,
   xtick={0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 18},
   ytick={0, 200, 2000, 20000, 200000, 2000000},
   legend pos=north west,
   ymajorgrids=true,
   grid style=dashed,
  ]

  \addplot[
  color=black,
 mark=square,
 ]
 coordinates {
(8.718, 1056785)
  };     
 \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is on the y-tick as you can see on the following image.

[image]

I want to show the interval {0, 200, 2000, 20000, 200000, 2000000} but everything is scaled on 10^6. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a log scale for the vertical axis

```
\documentclass[border = 4pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[         
    xlabel={Time (seconds)},
    ylabel={Exp},
    xmin=0, xmax=18,
    ymin=2, ymax=2000000,
    xtick={0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 18},
    ytick={2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000, 200000, 2000000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ymode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    ]

    \addplot[
    color=black,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
      (8.718, 1056785)
    };     
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !. Another question. If I dont's use "log ticks with fixed point", there is a way to use "ymode=log" starting from zero ?

Comment: @Discipulos you can’t. The reason being the fact that it is impossible to go from 0 to 1 by multiplying by a number